# ServiceStack.Redis Service availability

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I am trying to figure out how check the availability of the Redis Client.
The simple action of calling the client, will give me this information?
Is there a better method?

```
private RedisManagerPool redisPool;
public RedisCacheProviderStatus ServiceStatus()
{
    try
    {
        using (IRedisClient client = redisPool.GetClient())
        {
        }
        return RedisCacheProviderStatus.Available;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return RedisCacheProviderStatus.NotAvailable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a Redis Operation like `Ping()`:

```
using (var redis = redisPool.GetClient())
{
    return ((IRedisNativeClient)redis).Ping()
        ? RedisCacheProviderStatus.Available
        : RedisCacheProviderStatus.NotAvailable;
}
```

Comment: What if I do not see the Ping() method. I am using v4.0.30319 version

Comment: @AngeloBad Needs a cast to `((IRedisNativeClient)redis).Ping()`.